# Dev Client: No common URI schemes could be found for the native iOS and Android projects

Tags: android, react-native, expo, uri

I'm trying to run project on React Native using command `expo run:android`. Connected an android device.
Build successful. Then I get this message in console

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 30s 294 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 292
> up-to-date
>
> Dev Client: No common URI schemes could be found for the native iOS
> and Android projects, this is required for opening the project
>
> Add a common scheme with npx uri-scheme add my-scheme or provide a
> scheme with the --scheme flag
>
> You can see all of the existing schemes for your native projects by
> running npx uri-scheme list
>
> Starting Metro Bundler
>
> No scheme specified for development client

Check URI schemes by `npx uri-scheme list`

> › iOS: Schemes for config: ./ios\DogSafeProject\Info.plist
>
> › Android: Schemes for config:
> ./android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and running this script in my terminal got the job done

```
 yarn add expo-dev-client or
     npm install expo-dev-client
```

Answer (score 4):

That happened to me as well after upgrading dependencies in `package.json`.

You need to add `uri-scheme` package to your project with `npm install uri-scheme`, then recreate Android and iOS projects with `expo eject`. You may need to remove those directories and perform clean `expo eject` if still having error after install. After that `expo run:android` should work again :-)

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and running this script in my terminal got the job done.

```
npx uri-scheme add <app name>.
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply updated my expo-cli using: `yarn global add expo-cli` or `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because my npm start was set to "expo start --dev-client" where the flag was not supposed to be there